# How to configure MySQL connection properties with Spring, Hibernate 3.3 and c3p0?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0, apache-commons-dbcp

I am currently in the process of upgrading an application from Hibernate 3.2 to Hibernate 3.3.  I though I'd stick with the default connection pool (Hibernate changed its default from [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) to [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)) as I don't have any good reason to choose a non-default pool. At least non but having used DBCP before.

The upgrade went pretty much without any problems so far. The only thing I can't get to work is passing properties to the underlying MySQL [JDBC4Connection](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC4Connection.html). Up to now, I used DBCP's [BasicDataSource.addConnectionProperty(String,String)](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#addConnectionProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to pass properties (useUnicode=true, characterEncodin=UTF-8, characterSetResults=UTF-8, zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull).

However, I can't find any way to do the same with c3p0 other than [including them in the JDBC URL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). (That's something I'd like to avoid as I wanna keep the URL configurable without forcing users to include those parameters.)

So far, I've tried to use a [ConnectionCustomizer](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ConnectionCustomizer.html) without success. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again a question I answer myself (another self-learner? yes, please!):

[com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html) has a property "[properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html#getProperties())". Interestingly, setting properties after user and password overrides them. But setting properties before user and password works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Follow up for the self answer.
An example of a spring way of configuring this:

The Data source bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="properties" ref="mysqlConnectionProperties"></property>
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <!-- c3p0 combo pooled data source settings -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="7200" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="200" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="270" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery">
        <value>SELECT 1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The properties bean:

```
<bean id="mysqlConnectionProperties" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="useTimezone">true</prop>
            <prop key="serverTimezone">America/Chicago</prop>
                <!-- add any other properties you have -->
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```