# ResultSet field indices off by one

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

My SQL:

```
    String mainSql =
            " SELECT `subject`, `message_id`, `sender`, `date`, `type`, `order`, `body` "
            + " FROM `scan_result` sr LEFT OUTER JOIN `scan_result_body` srb ON `sr`.id = `srb`.scan_result_id "
            + " WHERE `user_id` = ? AND `message_id` = ? "
            + " ORDER BY `type`, `order` ASC ";
```

My code:

```
    try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(mainSql)) {
        int idx = 1;
        ps.setInt(idx++, userId);
        ps.setString(idx++, messageId);

        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            boolean firstRow = false;
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (!firstRow) {
                    firstRow = true;
                    builder.setSubject(rs.getString(1));
                    builder.setMessageId(rs.getString(2));
                    builder.setFrom(rs.getString(3));
                    builder.setDate(rs.getDate(4));
```

My error:

```
...whole 'body' field
</body>
</html>

' can not be represented as java.sql.Date
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getDateFast(ResultSetRow.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getDateFast(BufferRow.java:707)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2210)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2172)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getDate(NewProxyResultSet.java:3466)
    at me.unroll.bilbo.SQLRunner.getMime(SQLRunner.java:307)
```

When I run the SQL in MySQLWorkbench the result rows are as expected.  `date` is the 4th column.

The first three lines for getting the `subject`, `messageId` and `from` (or `sender`) work as expected. Fourth line somehow jumps to `body`. That is very weird.

I'm inspecting into the `ResultSet`. In particular here are the fields:

> Field[originalTableName=sr,columnName=subject,mysqlType=253(FIELD_TYPE_VAR_STRING)]
>   Field[originalTableName=sr,columnName=message_id,mysqlType=253(FIELD_TYPE_VAR_STRING)]
>   Field[originalTableName=sr,columnName=sender,mysqlType=253(FIELD_TYPE_VAR_STRING)]
>   Field[originalTableName=sr,columnName=date,mysqlType=7(FIELD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP)]
>   Field[originalTableName=srb,columnName=type,mysqlType=1(FIELD_TYPE_TINY)]
>   Field[originalTableName=srb,columnName=order,mysqlType=1(FIELD_TYPE_TINY)]
>   Field[originalTableName=srb,columnName=body,mysqlType=253(FIELD_TYPE_VAR_STRING)]

I abbreviated down to what I could ascertain is relevant (struck namespace on Field, memory address and irrelevant fields in the `Field`).  You can clearly see all 7, in order with the 4th being the date with the `FIELD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP`, all as I would expect.

`ResultSet.get` methods are indexed from `1`. This is true anyway and is further verified by the fact that I am accurately retrieving the subject and messageId, which I can tell by inspecting `builder`:

```
<1234567890.JavaMail.app@12345.abcde>
Voted Top 10 Best Magazines By Whoever
```

(Fields omitted but can clearly see is as expected).

Yet calling `rs.getDate(4)` blows everything up. Why? My next debugging step is to step my way through the implementation and see what's happening, but this is going to be a bit of work for me to set up properly, so posting on SO here.

Comment: Oh, my bad on that stray character.  Oops!

Comment: Props on using the builder pattern.  A timestamp may not be a date.  try java.sql.timestamp for the timestamp field.

Comment: @DwB same error - "<email body> can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp"

Comment: try executing the query by hand and reviewing that the output of the query is what you expect.

Comment: @DwB in my post: "When I run the SQL in MySQLWorkbench the result rows are as expected. date is the 4th column."

Comment: Try retrieving all columns as Strings to see the actual results.

Comment: @DwB the error message is dumping the result of the `body` column when I retrieve the date column, so I am seeing the actual result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43147/discussion-between-djechlin-and-dwb)

Comment: sorry, but I'm out of suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a MySQL bug we've had before where the date `0000-00-00` breaks everything.  One patch is to convert the date `0000-00-00` to `NULL` before reading. This is well-known and can be fixed via driver or connection properties. I'm positive there's a more standard way to do this, but this does the trick anyway:

```
String url = env.database().url;
char separator = url.contains("?") ? '&' : '?';
url += separator + "zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";

cpds.setJdbcUrl(url);
```

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1180131/1339987

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524493/1339987